# creating a binary tree and BST using (linked list) python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, binary-search-tree, b-tree

I'm trying to create BT and BST using linked list.
but you know that in python we don't have linked list.
So I should create a linked list class and then create my BT and BST classes.
if there are any other way I'm glad to listen to your ideas or helper codes.

Comment: A bit of googling would have found you this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-linked-list-representation-of-complete-tree-convert-it-to-linked-representation/

Comment: thanks bro :) @michaelmmeskhi